# Optimizing a recursive double linked list delete node multiple times

Tags: c++

I wrote a recursive doubly linked C++ functions to delete all the nodes in a doubly linked list having a certain value. Is it possible to optimize this? Thank you.

```
struct marynode {
    int value;
    marynode* next;
    marynode* prev;
};

void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(marynode*& llist, int value){
    marynode* tmp = llist;

    if (llist == NULL)
        return;

    if (llist->value == value){
            DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(llist->next, value); 
            if (llist->next == NULL){
                marynode* prev = llist->prev;
                delete llist;
                llist = NULL;
                llist = prev;
                if (llist)
                    llist->next = 0;
            }   
            else if (llist->prev == NULL){
                marynode* next = llist->next;
                delete llist;
                llist = NULL;
                llist = next;
                if (llist)
                    llist->prev = 0;
            }   
            else{
                marynode *x = llist;
                marynode  *mynext = x->next;
                while (x){
                    if (x->value == value){
                        marynode* clara = x->next;
                        marynode* zprev = x->prev;
                        delete x;
                        x = NULL;
                        x = clara;
                        llist = clara;
                        if (llist)
                            llist->prev = zprev;
                    }
                    else {
                        x = mynext;
                    }   
                    if (mynext){
                        mynext = mynext->next;
                    }
                }

            }
    }
    else{
            DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(llist->next, value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: “The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet.” - Michael A. Jackson

Comment: I've voted to close this question as "too localized" because it's asking how to improve your specific code. Can you find a way to ask your question such that people other than just you might be interested in the answer?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Thank you for your reply. I asked the question because doubly linked lists are used throughout many C++ application and recursion and iteration are used interchangeably. I could generalize the question to help more people if you wish? Thank you,

Comment: Thanks to being recursive, this cannot handle large lists anyway.

Comment: Uncle Bens, Are you this code will cause a stack overflow (no pun intended) on Windows or Linux? Is is possible to convert this code to a tail recursion version? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: I don't get why this all has to be so complicated. Crudely timed with std::clock, erasing a value from a list of 30000 items (can't seem to make much larger lists) takes ~0.4 seconds with your code, and ~0.0 seconds with `std::list` `li.remove(n);`

Comment: @UncleBens, Thank you for your reply and your statistics. This function was designed to multiple occurences of a single value rather a single value. I will try to profile STL LIst with multiple occurences but I think STL List will be O(Linear time) for many multiple ocuurences of a single value just like with recursion. Thank you.

Comment: `std::list::remove` removes all occurrences of the given value.

Comment: @UncleBens, Thank you for your reply. The time complexity of sTL LIST Remove is Order(linear time) according to www.cplusplus.com. THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something wrong with std::list?

Also, structs + global functions? You probably want to use object oriented constructs like member methods instead.

To optimize this particular code a little, I'd change your recursive call to a while loop.

```
while(llist != NULL) {
     if(llist->value == value) {
          if(llist->prev) {
              llist->prev->next = llist->next;
          }
          if(llist->next) {
              llist->next->prev = llist->prev;
          }
          node* next = llist->next;
          delete llist;
          llist = next;
     } else {
         llist = llist->next;
     }
}
```

Comment: Mark, Thank you for your reply. STL List hides the implementation of the doubly linked list from the user unless the user derives from the STL List in order to access the protected members of the STL List class. I believe that workingwith doubly linked lists is faster than using a STL List iterator. I will change the struct to a nested C++ class and put the global function in a doubly linked list C++ class. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, you really should profile your code to prove that std::list<> will prove to be a performance problem.  I doubt you will see any performance difference between your code and std::list<>, and would not be surprised if std::list<> is actually much faster.  Since there doesn't appear to be a reason NOT to use std::list<>, then answering this question becomes trivial with std::remove_if

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why you *need* to get at the internals of std::list. And I'd highly doubt you'd see a performance improvement using your own list implementation rather than the stl implementation. std::list is already doubly linked and they've most likely thought of all the corner cases.

Comment: @Chad, Thank you for your reply. I recently learned how to use the callgrind profiler and I will follow your suggestion to profile the code. The reason I reinvented a doubly linked list implementation is because I have looked at many open source C++ projects and most of them use double linked lists rather than STL List. Thank you.

Comment: Mark , Thank you for your reply. Are you sure a well optimized doubly linked list C++ implementation is not just as fast as STL List? I will profileover the weekend to find out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks way overkilling... why not just iterating over the list keeping only good nodes?

```
void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(marynode*& llist, int value)
{
    marynode *newfirst = NULL, *newlast = NULL;
    for (marynode *n=llist,*nn; n!=NULL; n=nn)
    {
        nn = n->next;
        if (n->value == value)
        {
            // Kill it
            delete n;
        }
        else
        {
            // Append at end of new list
            n->prev = newlast; n->next = NULL;
            if (newfirst == NULL) newfirst = n;
            if (newlast) newlast->next = n;
            newlast = n;
        }
    }
    llist = newfirst;
}
```

### EDIT

The above code is very efficient if most elements must be deleted, but does a lot of pointer fiddling if instead the elements being deleted are few (because reconstructs the whole lists using the same nodes). If the use case is the opposite is better to just iterate over the nodes and removing bad ones with a loop like the following

```
void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(marynode*& llist, int value)
{
    marynode *prev = NULL;
    marynode *n = llist;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n->value == value)
        {
            // Kill it
            marynode *nn = n->next;
            delete n;
            n = nn;
            // Fix links
            if (prev) prev->next = n; else llist = n;
            if (n) n->prev = prev;
        }
        else
        {
            // Move over to next one
            prev = n; n = n->next;
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

Another option is to try to optimize for both these extreme cases, basically either copying or deleting elements in "runs" with the tightest possible loop and only doing the eventually needed fixup at the end of the run...

```
void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(marynode *& list, int value)
{
    marynode *n = list;
    marynode *prev = NULL;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n->value == value)
        {
            // bad element: delete it and all following
            // consecutive bad elements
            do {
                marynode *nn = n->next;
                delete n;
                n = nn;
            } while (n && n->value == value);

            // fix the links only once per run
            if (prev) prev->next = n; else list = n;
            if (n) n->prev = prev;
        }
        else
        {
            // good element; just skip this and all
            // following good elements
            do {
                prev = n;
                n = n->next;
            } while (n && n->value != value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Warning: all presented code has not been tested (it hasn't been even compiled...)**

Comment: 6502, Thank you for your reply. I will test your idea. Thank you.

Comment: @6502: The performance of taking the given list and removing nodes or creating the new list depends on the frequency of removing a node. If a list contained 1000 nodes but you only wanted to remove 1, then your  implementation will spend a lot of time rebuilding the list almost exactly as is. On the other hand, if there are 1000 nodes and you want to remove 999, then yours will be very efficient and mine will waste a lot of writes.

Comment: @Mark: I added the dual code that works faster if the number of deletions is relatively small

Answer (score 1):

Why Not doing some refactoring over there and extract the essence of what you want to accomplish ?

something like (untested and not compiled)

```
void dll_link_nodes(node * theFirstNode, node *theNextNode){
    theFirstNode->next = theNextNode;
    theNextNode->prev = theFirstNode;
}

void dll_delete_node( marynode * theNode ){
    dll_link_nodes(theNode->prev, theNode->next);
    delete theNode;
}

node* dll_get_next_node (node* theNode){
    return theNode != NULL ? theNode->next : NULL;
}

inline int dll_node_get_value(node *n){
    return n->value;
}

void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(node*& llist, int value){
     node * iter = llist;

     while (iter != NULL){
         if ( dll_node_get_value(iter) == value) {
            node * target = iter;
            iter = dll_get_next_node(iter);
            dll_delete_node(target);
         }else
         {
             iter = dll_get_next_node(iter);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: fabrizioM, Thank you for your reply. Your answer looks very good. Have you tested it or profiled it yet? Thank your.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, Last night I found a way to optimize the C++ recursive implementation of DoublyLinkedListDeleteMultiple by changing 2 lines(please see // optimization). Thank you for everybody's answers and comments.

void DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(marynode*& llist, int value){
    marynode* tmp = llist;

```
if (llist == NULL)
    return;

if (llist->value == value){
        DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(llist->next, value); 
        if (llist->next == NULL){
            marynode* prev = llist->prev;
            delete llist;
            llist = NULL;
            llist = prev;
            if (llist)
                llist->next = 0;
        }   
        else if (llist->prev == NULL){
            marynode* next = llist->next;
            delete llist;
            llist = NULL;
            llist = next;
            if (llist)
                llist->prev = 0;
        }   
        else{
            marynode *x = llist;
            marynode  *mynext = x->next;
            int counter(0);
            while (x && counter++ < 1){               // Optimization
                if (x->value == value){
                    marynode* clara = x->next;
                    marynode* zprev = x->prev;
                    delete x;
                    x = NULL;
                    x = clara;
                    llist = clara;
                    if (llist)
                        llist->prev = zprev;
                }
                else {
                    x = mynext;
                }   
                if (mynext){
                    mynext = mynext->next;
                }
            }

        }
}
else{
        DoubleLinkedListDeleteMultiple(llist->next, value); 
}
```

}

Comment: I took out the counter code and replaced it with: if (x){ marynode* clara = x->next; node* zprev = x->prev; delete x; x = NULL; llist = clara; if (llist) llist->prev = zprev; } Now the recursive function has 8 fewer lines. Thank you.